# Group JSON object with counts of a field within groups

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, dictionary

I have Json data which I want to reorganise. Does anybody know the syntax to collect the 'matchingStatus' field count per 'file'/ key of the map ?

Example Json :

```
claimData = 
[{"id":1, "matchingStatus":"MATCHED", "fileName": "abcd.pdf", "amount":123.45},
{"id":2, "matchingStatus":"MATCHED", "fileName": "efg12.pdf", "amount":234.45},
{"id":3, "matchingStatus":"UNMATCHED", "fileName": "mnbv.pdf", "amount":100.00},
{"id":4, "matchingStatus":"MATCHED", "fileName": "kjhg.pdf", "amount":345.45},
{"id":5, "matchingStatus":"UNMATCHED", "fileName": "efg12.pdf", "amount":555.45},
{"id":6, "matchingStatus":"MATCHED", "fileName": "efg12.pdf", "amount":200.45},]
```

I have grouped the data by fileName :

```
this.groupedClaimFileMap = claimData.reduce(
  (entryMap, e) =>
    entryMap.set(e.fileName, [...(entryMap.get(e.fileName) || []), e]),
  new Map()
);
```

Returning example :

```
0: {"abcd.pdf" => Array(1)}
1: {"efg12.pdf" => Array(3)}
2: {"mnbv.pdf" => Array(1)}
3: {"kjhg.pdf" => Array(1)}
```

But now I also need to find the Percentage of 'Matched' status within the data of each file.
I had tried below but the count is nested within each iteration.

```
this.groupedSummary = claimData.reduce(
  (entryMap, e) =>
    entryMap.set(e.fileName, [
      [...(entryMap.get(e.fileName) || []), e],
      entryMap[e.matchingStatus]
        ? ++entryMap[e.matchingStatus]
        : (entryMap[e.matchingStatus] = 1),
      entryMap,
    ]),
  new Map()
);
```

Comment: You could, for each entry in the `groupedClaimFileMap`, `.filter()` the values of the array where `matchingStatus == ''MATCHED"` and then multiply the size of the filtered array by 100 and divide that by the size of the unfiltered array.

Comment: `entryMap[e.matchingStatus]` entryMap is a `Map` so you need to `get`. But putting all the logic inside the `set()` call doesn't lend itself to clarity.